# What causes azure websites to ignore settings from web.config?

Tags: azure, web-applications, web-config

My web.config contains multiple entries in "appSettings" (e.g.: twilio account key). One of these is for the asp.net chart control. It's the configuration part that states where the images the control generates are to be stored.

All of these settings work on my development machine. That is, i can connect to twilio and the chart control stores image in memory (as it should, according to the settings).

When i publish the site to my azure website (using vs), all of the settings work, *apart* from the chart control one. The chart control behaves as if the setting isn't even there. (it defaults to c:\TempImageFiles for storage).

I looked into the published version of the web.config and the setting is there. Only, it's beeing ignored.

My next attempt was to add that setting using the portal. (It's possible to add appSettings for a web app using the portal). I copied the exact same setting from web.config into the portal settings. This worked, so there is nothing wrong with what's in the settings.

So my question is: Why are some (at least this one) settings from web.config ignored when the app runs inside an azure web app?

Answer (score 1):

You might have an *app setting* defined in the Web App's configuration with an identical name that overrides the web.config setting. This is typically done to have production settings stored in Azure instead of Web.config.

You can confirm if this is the case by opening your Web App's blade in the new portal, and checking the **Application Settings** tab there.

Comment: well, yes, it's there. It did not have an entry for the chart control though. as i said: the setting turned up as available only after i added it to appsettings in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

azure websites / azure web app service are typical web applications running on top of azure PaaS infrastructure. So whatever storage allocated to the service is accessible from the app. But it cannot be the typical C: or D:  where in a regular server the app may have complete access. Mostly the C: space is allocated for IIS hosting. D:\local is something you can utilize as the app will have complete read and write access.

Please refer azure web app service sandbox details [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

If you are accessing the path via code try using Server.MapPath property to get access to the path. options like Path.GetTempPath() will not work.

One point to note is, any local storage in azure PaaS services is to be treated like a temporary storage. Whenever the site, service or role recycles the storage will be gone a fresh storage will be assigned.

Comment: Your point about local storage in PaaS services is incorrect. Namely in web apps (the focus of your answer), local storage is *durable* and accessible by all web app instances. And local storage survives the adding and removing of instances (though storage is removed if the entire web app is deleted). With VMs and cloud services (web/worker role instances) local storage is ephemeral / non-durable.

Comment: well, first of all, i think that local storage is _not_ temporary storage. when you deploy the website including it's web.config, everything stays available. (otherwise, the website would vanish, wouldn't it?)

also, i'm of course not accessing the appsettings in web.config by reading the file myself. i'm using the configuration code for that, and this works. (as i said, all other settings are available, only that special one is not.)

apart from that: that special setting isn't even read by my code in any way at all: The chart control reads that all on it's own.

Comment: I did not say it is temporary but I meant to treat it like temporary. If the instance for some reason is recycled  or deleted you will lose the stored data.  And it is always better to have an out of proc storage like blob storage so that it is always available across all instances and other related apps.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just not true, at least in the case that i mentioned. i'm talking about the web.config file that is deployed as part of the website. It will absolutely be available, even if the instance gets recycled. If that would not be the case, no asp.net website would be working on azure.

Maybe my questions wasn't clear enough: It appears you are trying to answer an different question :-)

Comment: I was not talking about a web.config. talking more on the local storage inside the website. Also if I make some change in the web.config ( in a web role) by remotely connecting to it and when the role recycles the changes would be gone. I have not tried the same with web app service.